# Undefined $class_name no autoloader usando spl_autoloader_register() com WAMP?

Tags: php, spl

Eu estou tentando implementar um autoloader para classes no meu projeto, porem nao consigo fazer esse codigo funcionar... Ele retorna a variavel $class_name como Undefined.

```
function autoload_classes( $class_name ) {
   if ( ! empty( $class_name ) && file_exists( $class_name ) ) {
      include get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/classes/' . $class_name . '.php';
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
spl_autoload_extensions( '.php' );
spl_autoload_register( 'autoload_classes' );
```

Poderiam me ajudar?
Obrigado!

Comment: Poderia traduzir a perguntar?

Comment: Caraca!! Desculpa nem percebi kkkkk pera ae....

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://devcia.com/criando-um-autoload-turbinado/

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem um *autoload* que eu utilizo:

```
function search_lib($lib, $file, $ds = '/'){
   // Verifica se o diretório informado é válido
   if (is_dir($lib)){

      // Verifica se o arquivo já existe neste primeiro diretório
      if (file_exists($lib.$ds.$file)) return $lib.$ds.$file;

      // Lista os subdiretórios e arquivos
      $dirs = array_diff(scandir($lib, 1), array('.','..'));
      foreach ($dirs as $dir) {

         // Verifica se é um arquivo se for, pula para o próximo
         if (!is_dir($lib.$ds.$dir)) continue;

         // Se for um diretório procura dentro dele
         $f = search_lib($lib.$ds.$dir, $file, $ds);

         // Caso não encontre retora false
         if ($f !== false) return $f;
      }

   }

   // Se o diretório informado não for válido ou se não tiver encontrado retorna false
   return false;
}
spl_autoload_register(
   function ($class){

      //if (strpos($class, '\\') !=- -1)
      //   $class = end( explode('\\', $class) );

      $libs = __DIR__.DS;
      $ext  = '.class.php';

      $file = search_lib($libs, $class.$ext);

      // Se encontrou inclui o arquivo
      if ($file !== false ) require_once $file;
      // Se não encontrar o arquivo lança um erro na tela. :)
      else {
         $msg = "Autoload fatal erro: Can't find the file {$class}{$ext} on {$libs}!";
         error_log($msg);
         exit('<br><br><strong>'.$msg.'</strong>');
      }

   }
);
```

Ele busca a classe dentro do diretório (e seus sub-diretórios) na variável `$libs` da função anonima no `spl_autoload_register`. A extensão dos arquivos de classe é configurada na variável `$ext` logo abaixo (eu uso `.class.php`, basta alterar para seu padrão).

**Obs.:** O código usa uma constante `DS` que é um aliás que eu criei para `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, caso você não utilize assim basta alterar, ou se quiser defina-a.